# Angular - If checkbox is checked change value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Controller:**

```
promiseObj.physical = $http.get('search?sumBoth=1&customer=' + customer).success(function(data) {

$scope.servers = data; // get data from json

});
```

**View:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in servers | filter: { _id: { idc: item._id.idc } }">
            <td>{{data._id.cluster}}</td>
            <td>{{data.Physical.SumCores}}</td>
            <td>{{data.Virtual.SumCores}}</td>
            <td>{{data.Physical.SumMemory}}</td>
</tr>

Oversubscription? <input type="checkbox" name="oversubscription" />
```

What I am trying to do is to change `<td>{{data.Virtual.SumCores}}</td>` to `<td>{{data.Virtual.SumCores/4}}</td>` if over subscription is equal to true

Fairly new to angular and I am still learning:

Do I do this in the view or the controller?

What is the best approach?

Comment: does the `oversubscription` apply to the entire repeat or only specific elements?

Comment: Instead of changing the databinding, I would bind the td's to a new set of variables that get recalculated on the ng-change of the checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in the view - just be sure to give your checkbox a `ngModel`

```
Oversubscription? <input type="checkbox" ng-model="overSubscription" name="oversubscription" />

<td>{{overSubscription ? (data.Virtual.SumCores / 4) : data.Virtual.SumCores}}</td>
```

Or, with an `ngChange` on the checkbox and some controller logic:

```
Oversubscription? <input type="checkbox" ng-change="calcCores(overSubscription) ng-model="overSubscription" name="oversubscription" />
```

Controller:

```
$scope.calcCores = function(checked) {
    $scope.servers = $scope.servers.map(function(server) {
        server.Virtual.SumCores = checked ? (server.Virtual.SumCores / 4) : server.Virtual.SumCores
        return server;
    });
}
```

Comment: @CMS -- Controller method is probably more efficient - the view method will get processed each time the `$digest` cycle is executed (depending on your app - could be a lot).